# How to get my Autocomplete input field to reset DefaultValue after submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

How can I get my `<TextField>` inside Autocomplete to reset it's default value after form submit?

Currently, the state of formValues during submit remains as the default value?

I've tried to fix the onSubmit function of my form to clear the state of the values, but not able to do so.

How can I clear the value after a user submits?

```
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState()

  const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
  {  
    console.log(data);

    axiosInstance
      .patch(URL + slug + '/', {
        stock_list: data.stock_list.map(list=>list.symbol),
      })
      .then((res) =>
      {
        getFinData(dispatch)(slug);
        SetFormValues([''])
        console.log(formValues)
      });
  };

  console.log(formValues)

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Grid>
            <form noValidate  onSubmit = { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
              <Controller
              render={({ onChange ,...props }) => (
                <Autocomplete
                    {...props}
                    className={classes.inputBar}
                  id="stock_list"
                  key={formValues}
                    name="stock_list"
                    multiple
                    options={options}
                    ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
                    renderGroup={renderGroup}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    // onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
                    onChange={(e, data) => { onChange(data); SetFormValues(data) }}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.symbol === value.symbol}
                    renderOption={(option) =>
                    {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <span style={{ fontWeight: 500, fontSize: "20px", paddingRight: "1rem" }}>{option.symbol}</span><span style={{ color: "#C6C6C6", fontSize: "24px" }}> | </span><span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{option.company}</span>
                        </>
                      )
                    }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                      <Zoom in={tabSwitch === 0}>
                      <TextField 
                        {...params}
                        style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        id="stock_list"
                        name="stock_list"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Companies"
                        className={classes.inputBar}
                        defaultValue={formValues}
                      />
                      </Zoom>
                       )}
                      />
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={formValues}
                    // onChange={([, data]) => data}
              />
              {formValues && formValues.length > 0 &&
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                type="submit"
                style={{display:"flex",alignItems: 'center',justifyContent:"center"}}
                >
                  Add Stocks
            </Button>
              }
            </form> 
        </Grid>
          </div>
      </Container>

    );
})
```

UPDATE:
I have tried implementing your codes but still no success in removing the data from original state?

```
  const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState([])


  const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
  {  
    console.log(data);

    axiosInstance
      .patch(URL + slug + '/', {
        stock_list: data.stock_list.map(list=>list.symbol),
      })
      .then((res) =>
      {
        getFinData(dispatch)(slug);
        SetFormValues([]);
      });
  };

  return (
              <Controller
              render={({ onChange ,...props }) => (
                <Autocomplete
                    {...props}
                    className={classes.inputBar}
                    id="stock_list"
                    key={formValues}
                    name="stock_list"
                    multiple
                    options={options}
                    ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
                    renderGroup={renderGroup}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    onChange={(e, data) => { onChange(data); SetFormValues(data) }}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.symbol === value.symbol}
                    renderOption={(option) =>
                    {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <span style={{ fontWeight: 500, fontSize: "20px", paddingRight: "1rem" }}>{option.symbol}</span><span style={{ color: "#C6C6C6", fontSize: "24px" }}> | </span><span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{option.company}</span>
                        </>
                      )
                    }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                      <Zoom in={tabSwitch === 0}>
                      <TextField 
                        {...params}
                        style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        id="stock_list"
                        name="stock_list"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Companies"
                        className={classes.inputBar}
                        defaultValue={formValues}
                        value={formValues}
                      />
                      </Zoom>
                       )}
                      />
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={[]}
              />
```

It might be worth noting that my Mui AutoComplete and textfield is wrapped around by React Hook Form controller.

Comment: can you please create a demo on stackbliz....

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your code.

When using state, specify the data type to be stored.
E.g

1. if  you are storing array of data, your state should be  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState([]);` not  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState()`;
2. if  you are storing string of data, your state should be  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState("");` not  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState()`;
3. if  you are storing integer of data, your state should be  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState(0);` not  `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState()`;

To clear the state of each of these data

1. For Array

   `SetFormValues([]);`
2. For String

   `SetFormValues("");`
3. For Int

   `SetFormValues(0);`

So correct your code and ty again. It will work for you.
put this code in the `then` callback of axios `SetFormValues([]);`

Comment: Hey, thank you, please see my new update. Still not able to fix  issue.

Comment: @woof  use this `const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState(null)` .Put this code in the then callback of axios `SetFormValues(null);`

Comment: @woof I have posted a new answer. Try it will work

Answer (score 0):

Because defaultValue is default value..

Try looks like this; (add value)

```
<TextField 
  style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
  id="stock_list"
  name="stock_list"
  variant="outlined"
  label="Companies"
  defaultValue={formValues}
  value={formValues}
/>
```

---

https://material-ui.com/api/input/#main-content

**defaultValue:** The default input element value. Use when the component is not controlled.

**value:** The value of the input element, required for a controlled component.

Comment: I just tried doing this, couldn't get it to work. Still the same behavior is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState(null)
```

Put this code in the then callback of axios `SetFormValues(null);`

OR

```
const [formValues, SetFormValues] = useState([])
```

Put this code in the then callback of axios `SetFormValues(null);`

If any of those two above does not work for you, try storing the values as string in state

E.g const `[formValues, SetFormValues] = useState("")`
and clear items using `SetFormValues(null)` or `SetFormValues("");`